# Asp.Net Core: How do I display an image?

Tags: css, asp.net-core, .net-core

Hey I tried to make a page in Asp.Net Core and I want to put an image in the background but the way I tried wasn't very successfully.

```
<style>
    .body {
        background-image: url('..\pictures\mypicture.jpg');
    }
</style>
```

Or when I tried to make a normal picture it didn't work either:

```
<img src="..\picture\mypicture.png"/>
```

Comment: put the `pictures` folder under `wwwroot` and make sure you have [`app.UseStaticFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#serve-files-inside-of-web-root) in startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first make sure your picture folder is in wwwroot and make sure you have 
`app.UseStaticFiles()` in startup. ,after than, try this :

```
<img src="/picture/mypicture.png"/>
```

or

```
<style>
   .body {
          background-image: url('~/pictures/mypicture.jpg');
         }
</style>
```